# How to Android Studio load libs from other websize,like github

Tags: android

I want to add a libs where in github to my project.For Testing, I create a new project,and add project according to README file, but I get a error.
**Error:Failed to resolve: com.borjabravo.readmoretextview:1.1.1:**

https://github.com/borjabravo10/ReadMoreTextView (this is project link)

compile 'com.borjabravo.readmoretextview:1.1.1'  this is order

here is my porject build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.caoguodong.textreadmoretext"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.borjabravo.readmoretextview:1.1.1'
}
```

this is my root build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Looks okay to me... You can try to add `repositories { jcenter()  }` to the build.gradle

Comment: I hope you have tried syncing the gradle a several time before posting the question here (and that you are connected to Internet while syncing). I don't know if that's necessary but the build.gradle file in the Link you provided has some more classpath in the dependencies part.

Comment: Maybe you can try this dependencie: compile 'com.borjabravo.readmoretextview:1.1.0' maybe there could be a problem with the newiest version.

Comment: I got andswer,the path is wrong. shuold be "com.borjabravo:readmoretextview:1.1.1",

Comment: @DeepakTalan I try to many times, but always wrong

Comment: haha..that was a very silly mistake..